# terraform - Regroup nested map into a list of list

Tags: terraform

I have a complicated issue, and i dont figure out how to resolve it.
As input i have a variable like this

```
  policy_rules = {
      zone1_to_zone2 = { 
        from_zone = ["zone1"]
        source = ["titi-01", "toto-01"]
        to_zone = ["zone2"]
        destination = ["any"]
        application = ["TCP_22"]
      }
      zone2_to_zone3 = { 
        from_zone = ["zone2"]
        source = ["titi-01", "toto-01"]
        to_zone = ["zone3"]
        destination = ["any"]
        application = ["TCP_22"]
      }
      zone1_to_zone3 = { 
        from_zone = ["zone1"]
        source = ["titi-01", "toto-01"]
        to_zone = ["zone3"]
        destination = ["any"]
        application = ["TCP_22"]
      }
      zone1_to_zone22 = { 
        from_zone = ["zone1"]
        source = ["titi-01", "toto-01"]
        to_zone = ["zone2"]
        destination = ["any"]
        application = ["TCP_22"]
      }
      zone2_to_zone1 = { 
        from_zone = ["zone2"]
        source = ["titi-01", "toto-01"]
        to_zone = ["zone1"]
        destination = ["any"]
        application = ["TCP_22"]
      }
      zone3_to_zone1 = { 
        from_zone = ["zone3"]
        source = ["titi-01", "toto-01"]
        to_zone = ["zone1"]
        destination = ["any"]
        application = ["TCP_22"]
      }
 
    }
```

As ressource i have

```
resource "junos_security_policy" "demo_policy" {
  from_zone = "zone1"
  to_zone   = "zone2"

  policy {
    name                      = "allow_trust"
    match_source_address      = ["any"]
    match_destination_address = ["any"]
    match_application         = ["any"]
  }
}
```

The first issue is that multiple rules with same from_zone / to_zone use the same ressource with multiple policy blocks, it can be resolve with a dynamic one:

```
resource "junos_security_policy" "this" { 
  # for_each = ?                                                                                                                 
  from_zone = "zone1"
  to_zone   = "zone2"

  dynamic "policy" {
    for_each = local.policy_rules
    iterator = rule

    content {
      name                      = rule.key
      match_source_address      = rule.value.source
      match_destination_address = rule.value.destination
      match_application         = rule.value.application
    }
  }
}
```

The main problem is how to create create dynamic resources that regroup the rules with same from_zone / to_zone ?

This exemple takes 3 zones, but potentially much more, so making all combination is not an option...
I thougth by passing thru a mapping maybe and a temporary list(list(string)) that could contains all rules keys grouped with same from_zone / to_zone and then making some lookup to load the correct values but i dont figure out how to do

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the values for the objects always the same between elements as demonstrated in the question? Will there be redundant elements as shown in the question? Is this variable being used elsewhere, or can it be optimally restructured without side effects?